# MediaPlayer in Service

Tags: java, service, media-player

```
public class MyService extends Service {
   @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");

}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    musicSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
    musicSound.setLooping(true);

}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    musicSound.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    musicSound.stop();

}
```

Hi all. I am a newbie, just learning. I need the app to turn off the music when minimized. The options via onPause and onStop (in the activation) are not suitable because they are triggered when switching between activations within the application. I will be grateful if you can write the code.